# retry code segment multiple times with different intervals

Tags: java, android, algorithm, retry-logic

I want to have an algorithm for part of my android app code which will execute a particular code segment again and again if it doesnt meet the condition with different time intervals. in simple words retry the code multiple times after different time intervals.

For examaple, 
I am uploading some string data, when there is an internet connectionI do a network connection check, and when there is no internet, it should check again automatically after 1 min. if positive, data is uploaded and if not, it should retry again after next 3 mins and for the third time also if positive, data is uploaded and if not, it should do the final check after next 5 mins and then if it cant get network then it should show toast no network.

How to do that with a simple algorithm?

Here the network connection scenario is just as an example. I want the algorithm for the 'retry' as i have explained there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ConnectivityManager(For internet check)`  with _Timer,  CountDownTimer or Handler_ will be used in your requirement.

Comment: @Piyush Here the network connection scenario is just as an example. I want the algorithm for the 'retry' as i have explained there. Thanks

Comment: For retry i have given an options

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to declare a method to check if there's internet connection.

Using `ConnectivityManager` and `NetworkInfo`

```
public static boolean hasInternetConnection(final Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni == null) {
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}
```

Then...

```
try{
        if(Util.hasInternetConnection(mcontext)){
            //todo

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                   showAlertDialog("Alert",message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFail(String errorcode, String errormessage) {
                    showAlertDialog("Alert",errormessage);
                }
            });
        }else{
            showInternetRequiredDialog(getString(R.string.title_internet_require), getString(R.string.msg_no_internet_connection_setup));
            return;
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

As for how you wanna write your checking logic, I'll leave it up to you

Answer (score 0):

Using Handler, Timer can help.